# Manage IBM Server X3650 M4 on Maas

Tags: maas

I've 4 IBM Server X3650 M4 and I'd like to manage them on MAAS but I don't know how to make to change their status From New to Ready.

I've booted and see one of them on MAAS, but I don't know what selecting as BMC to run the commission of nodes. I saw that on its Power configuration there is this sets.

[image]

Someone knows how I've to procedure? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has my same issue I've resolved that with this post from MAAS support forum: [Manage IBM Server X3650 M4 on MAAS](https://discourse.maas.io/t/manage-ibm-server-x3650-m4-on-maas/299)

[image: screenshot]